# Get text from page?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have this HTML code:

```
<p class="lottiindividuati">
Lotti individuati:
<strong>1499</strong>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_pagine"> - pagina 1 di 150</span>
<br>
</p>
```

where the number "1499" is dynamic and the text "pagina 1 di 150" is dynamic too.
I need to save 1499 and 150 in two different variables.
How can I do this? I'm trying 
Thank for your time

Answer (score 1):

For the first value, the "1499", you can use the fact that it is the only text of the strong element:

```
value1 = browser.p(:class => 'lottiindividuati').strong.text
p value1
#=> "1499"
```

For the second value, "150", you can use the fact that it is part of the text of the only span element. Using a regular expression, you can get number at the end of that span's text.

```
value2 = browser.p(:class => 'lottiindividuati').span.text[/\d+$/]
p value2
#=> "150"
```